# Why doesn't StencilJS "hydrate" components in <svg> tags?

Tags: svg, stenciljs

I have a Stencil component that should draw SVG shapes over an image.

If I generate the shapes (simple rect below) directly in the svg tag, it's ok, but if I use Stencil subcomponents instead, they're not hydrated.

But they are if I place them outside the svg tag (of course they do not render properly scaled over the image in this case...)

```
render() {
return (
  <Host>
    <svg viewBox={this.size}>
      <image xlinkHref={this.Image} x="0" y="0"
        width={this.width} height={this.height}
        preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
      />
      {this.Bands.map((d) => // THESE ARE NOT HYDRATED
        <bands-list data={d} />
      )}
      {this.Bands.map(() => // BUT THIS IS SHOWN CORRECTLY
        <rect x={0} y={0} width={100} height={100} />
      )}
    </svg>
    {this.Bands.map((d) => // HYDRATED, but outside SVG...
      <bands-list data={d} />
    )}
  </Host>
);
}
```

here is what it produces :

[image]

what am I missing please ?

Comment: I'm not sure custom elements are supposed to work in the SVG namespace? There's a way of embedding foreign object types though (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/extend.html#EmbeddingForeignObjects), using `<foreignObject>` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)... maybe you can get it to work with that.

Comment: apparently they don't, but why ? What's the "correct" way of rendering web-components dynamically in svg ?

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong, you are using custom Web Components to dynamically render SVGs. Not WebComponents *inside* SVGs. Think of it that way - SVG is its own language for basically everything vector-related, basically *any* HTML *inside* SVG doesn't make sense. If you want a WebComponent as an abstraction for dynamically generated SVG content, you either generate the whole SVG our you could give [StencilJS functional components](https://stenciljs.com/docs/functional-components) a try.

Stencil components won't *"hydrate"* *inside* SVG, because they are at the heart of it all WebComponents, which are not supported *within* SVGs. Although you could use `<foreignObject>` I doubt it will serve you needs.